# Temporary table store in SQLite on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, database, optimization, sqlite

I use temporary tables in an SQLite based iPhone application. Performance was not as   was required so I looked at various candidates for optimization. Most of these worked well and had the desired effect. However, I'd also like to try [moving the temporary tables from flash into memory](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_temp_store) to see if there is any improvement.

On an actual device I try and configure this using:

```
PRAGMA temp_store = 2;
```

These executes without error. However, when I query the configuration using:

```
PRAGMA temp_store;
```

No results are returned so I am unable verify that this configuration is in effect. I can read other PRAGMA settings such as 'page_size'. Can anyone tell me:

- If this is expected behavior
- If this is an unsupported configuration in SQLite on the iPhone
- If such an optimization would be pointless on the iPhone even if it were possible (due perhaps to the hardware)
- How I can successfully move temporary table storage into memory in this scenario

**Note:** I am well aware of Core Data in SDK 3.0 but I have good reasons for not using it.

**Update:** jitter pointed out that the SQLite instance on the iPhone may have been compiled with [SQLITE_TEMP_STORE](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#temp_store) set to always use temporary files. I wasn't aware of this setting - is there any way to confirm that this is the case?

Comment: Elaborate on what optimizations did you already make? And what is the usage scenario. Maybe some other tips come then flying in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added the SQLite source myself to my projects, because the SQLite on at least the iPhone OS 2.x is not thread safe.

Comment: That's a very interesting point. Can you tell me how you discovered that the standard version is not thread safe?

Comment: I guesshe used the sqlite3_threadsafe() function. http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/threadsafe.html

Comment: the default iphone sqlite dylib spewed out a lot of warnings/errors when accessing tables from multiple threads.

Comment: See here: http://www.v2ex.com/2008/11/22/full-text-search/ on how to make it compile. 
and http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6

Answer (score 1):

I don't know but guess they compiled the sqllite with SQLITE_TEMP_STORE=0. And there is another guy who tried this and didn't succeed. [SQLite optimization on the iPhone](http://swish-movement.blogspot.com/2009/05/sqlite-optimization-on-iphone.html)

- List item

I can't try it out myself but there seems to be a `sqlite3TempInMemory()` function in the source too ([src/main.c](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/fileview?f=sqlite/src/main.c&v=1.559)). Don't know if you can call that.

> This function returns true if
>   main-memory should be used instead of
>   a temporary file for transient pager
>   files and statement journals. The
>   value returned depends on the value of
>   db->temp_store (runtime parameter) and
>   the compile time value of
>   SQLITE_TEMP_STORE. The following table
>   describes the relationship between
>   these two values and this functions
>   return value.

Comment: This is all becoming a bit self referential (the link goes to my blog post :-) I was hoping that I had overlooked something.

Comment: haha!! should really have noted the avatar the linked in stackoverflow flair.

Comment: added function call you might want to try out